# Changing the property value programmatically or data bind it in Polymer

Tags: data-binding, properties, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to change the URL inside my iron-ajax element according to a number retrieved from the page URL. To do so I am creating the URL with the computed property that takes the number I retrieved.
The problem I am having is that I don't know how to change the value (which is the number that will get appended to the URL) inside my properties programmatically. To work around it I tried to set the Number inside my HTML and then data bind it to the property. However I cant get that to work either.
When I hardcode the value for the userId inside my properties everything works fine so I believe the mistake must be with my data binding. It would be great if someone could point me in the direction what I am doing wrong. However if there is a better solution such as setting the value for the userId programmatically please let me know.

```
<dom-module id="my-profile-view">

  <template>
    <style></style>

    <iron-ajax
      auto
      id="requestSingleUser"
      url="{{url}}"
      handle-as="json"
      last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax>

    <span id="stdNr" userId="{{55}}"></span>

  </template>

  <script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-profile-view',

    properties: {
      route: Object,

      userId: {
        value: '',
        notify: true
      },

      url: {
        computed: 'computeURL(userId)'
      },

    },

    ready: function() {
      //Get's the URL and strips it down to the nuber
      var getUrl = window.location.href;
      var stdudentNumber = getUrl.split("/").pop();

      //Set the number to then bind it back to the value inside the properties
      var stdId = this.$$("#stdNr");
      stdId.setAttribute('userId','{{20}}');
    },

    computeURL: function(userId) {
      return['http://api.dev/user/' + userId];
    },

  });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems.

I think it should be like this

```
<span id="stdNr">[[userId]]</span>
```

Your `userID` property isn't  properly defined it should be

```
 userId: {
   type: String,
   value: ''
 }
```

Then in your ready function you would do something like this

```
ready: function() {
  //Get's the URL and strips it down to the nuber
  var getUrl = window.location.href;
  //Set the number to then bind it back to the value inside the properties
  this.userId = getUrl.split("/").pop();
},
```

finally you computed function should return a string not an array

```
computeURL: function(userId) {
  return 'http://api.dev/user/' + userId;
```

Although do you really need to put the full domain name in the url, won't it just be relative to the same domain the rest of the application comes from?

The setting of `this.userId` will automatically make the computed url Work

Comment: Thanks @akc42 I added the notify true to the property because i tried to bind the value with the one set in the span
Obviously your way is much cleaner which makes my attempt to bind redundant.
Regarding the URL, I have a page that displays users when a user is clicked it opens the profile. At the moment I pass the clicked id through my url. The page you see strips the url down to the id and requests the data. Thats why i still need the full domain path as it is different from the api url.
However if I find a example on how to use sessions in Polymer I will change that

Comment: You need to know when the url of the calling page changes.  This is a bit complicated - but you could do it by adding an event listener to the windows 'popstate' event, or take a close look at `<iron-location>` which exposes the `path` as a variable which you can put an observer on.  notify is only needed on a property if it needs to notify outside of the element, not needed if its just within the element - that happens automatically